# Werkzeug and SQLAlchemy 0.5x session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, werkzeug

Updated:

Going through the Werkzeug [link text](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/0.5.1) tutorial, got stack with creating SQLAlchemy session using sessionmaker() instead of create_session() as recommended.

Note: it is not about SA, it is about Werkzeug.

Werkzeug tutorial:

```
session = scoped_session(lambda: create_session(bind=application.database_engine,
    autoflush=True, autocommit=False), local_manager.get_ident)
```

I asked how to achieve the same using sessionmaker():

As a result guys from #pocoo RCI helped me with this:

```
session = scoped_session(lambda: sessionmaker(bind=application.database_engine)(),
    local_manager.get_ident)
```

without **()** at the end of sessionmaker(**args) it kept giving me an error:

RuntimeError: no object bound to application

P.S. if delete **lambda** it will not work.

Answer (score 4):

`sessionmaker()` returns a session factory, not a session itself. `scoped_session()` takes a session factory as argument. So just omit the `lambda:` and pass the result of `sessionmaker()` directly to `scoped_session()`.

Comment: Didn't mention it, I am playing with Werkzeug lib and SA. I am trying to adopt SA  sessionmaker() instead of session_create() as SA Tutorial recommends to do it.

Guys from #pocoo IRC helped me but I still didn't get it what the trick was it. They added "()" at the end of sessionmaker() and now it works.

session = scoped_session(lambda: sessionmaker(bind=application.database_engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)(), local_manager.get_ident)

Comment: You're making more work for yourself, your code's readers, and your python interpreter by writing it that way instead of listening to Ants Aasma.  You're also breaking your `scoped_session`.  Your code creates a `sessionmaker`, and then calls it (returning a session), and passes that session in a lambda to `scoped_session`.  So each time `scoped_session` tries to return a new session, it actually returns the same session.  Omit the `lambda`, and drop the () from the end of your sessionmaker call.  `scoped_session(sessionmaker(*args))`